# Android line simplification

Tags: android

I'm looking for some best practice advice.

I have create an app (very like mytracks) which collects GPS measurements and displays them on a map. I want to be able to record GPS data for ideally 24 hours at a 10 second interval. This is a lot of data, so I am not keeping it in memory, i'm storing it into an SQLiteDB as it arrives. Inside the draw() functions I am selecting everything and drawing it as a Path object.

My above approach works great until I have > 4 hours worth of data. Then the draw function takes for ever to execute which makes the application seem very slow.

I think what I need to do is draw a simplified trajectory onto the map. My question is what is the best way of doing this.

i) Processor heavy: In draw() select everything from the SQLiteDB, construct the simplified trajectory, draw it on the map.

ii) Memory heavy: Maintain a simplified trajectory in memory, update it as new data arrives, in draw() simply draw it to the map.

iii) Magic: Use some special OverlayLay that I don't know about which handles line simplification for you.

Kind regards,
Cathal

Answer (score 1):

My initial semi-random thoughts:

1. You don't say that you're actually doing so, but *don't* store one sample per database table row. 24 hours of samples at 10 second intervals, that's 8640 samples. Each sample is 2 doubles, i.e 16 bytes. A day's worth of data is 135KB, a sum which can easily fit entirely in memory. Your database strategy should probably be to let one table row correspond to one sampling period, whose maximum length is one day. Needless to say, the sample data should be in a BLOB field.
2. Drawing the path: this depends on the current map zoom and what part of the sample set is visible. The first thing you do is to iterate your sample collection (max. 8640) and determine the subset which is visible at the current zoom. That should be a pretty quick operation. Lets say for sake of example 5000 are visible. You then select some maximum number of samples for the path based on h/w assumptions... picking a number out of thin air let's say no more than 500 samples used for the path (i.e. the device won't struggle to draw a path with 500 points). You therefore build the path using every 10th sample (5000/500 = 10), and make sure to include the first and last sample of the visible set.

Note that you don't do *all* this work every frame. You only need to recalculate the path when the user finishes panning or zooming the map. The rest of the time you just draw the path you already calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, I was just looking at code I wrote to do something similar, about 5 years ago.

Here are the steps I went through:

- **Simplify** the dataset to only visible detail. I designed with several pluggable simplification strategies, but a common interface for tolerances and feeding in/getting out points to render. More on how to design it below.
- **Cache** a compact, fast-to-access version of the simplified point list.  For big data sets, it's helpful to use primitives as much as possible, in preference to Point objects.  With `double` precision locations, you need 128 bytes per point, or ~1.3 MB of memory for 10,000.
- **Render** efficiently, and without creating garbage.  Iterating through int/float/double arrays of x and y coordinates is best, with a tight rendering loop that does as much as possible outside the loop.  You'll be AMAZED how many points you can render at once if it's just "plot this path."
- **Notify** the Simplifier when new points are added, and run new points through this before adding them to the cached point list.  Update it as needed, but try to just process the latest.

**Simplification Interface:**
There's a bunch of ways to implement this. The best one (for huge point sets) is to feed it an `Iterator<Point>` and let the simplification algorithm go to work with that.  This way, the points don't all have to be in memory, and you can feed it from a DB query.  For example, the Iterator can wrap a JDBC ResultSet.  Simplifiers should also have a "tolerance" value to determine how close points are before they get ignored.

**How to simplify pointsets/polygonal lines:**
There are a bunch of algorithms.

- The simplest is to remove points that are less than $tolerance from the last included point. This is an O(n) implementation.
- The [Douglas-Peucker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) algorithm gives an excellent polygon simplification on a large pointset.  The weakness is that you need to operate on points in memory; use it on batches of, say, 10,000 points at a time.  Runs in O(n log n) average, O(n^2) worst case
- Fancy 2D hashing:  you can use a 2D hashing algorithm, with one entry possible per pixel.  Points that map to an occupied slot aren't rendered. You'll need to run through points twice for this, to find points that lead back to the same spots, if rendering lines and not scatterplots.

**Extra tips:**

- You can boost performance by creating a wrapper that maps your cached, simplified point list to something your graphics primitives can handle easily.  I was using Swing, so I created something that acted like a mutable Path2D, which the rendering context could handle directly.
- Use your primitives.  Seriously, I can't say this enough. If you use objects to store memory, the 128 bytes/point can double, AND increase memory use AND it can't be compiled to such optimal code.

Using these strategies, it is possible to render millions of points at once (in a reduced form). If I recall correctly, I could run the simplification routine in real-time, operating on 10k+ points at a time, using good code. It might have been 100k+ points. If you can store a hashtable with one slot per pixel, the hashing implementation is ridiculously fast (I know, it was my fastest solution)